# How should I shape my left hand when playing power chords?

Tags: guitar, chords

So I've been casually been playing guitar for a few years. I've recently realised my hand position when playing power chords feels and looks wrong. All the desired strings play clearly but the position of my left hand feels really uncomfortable and it feels really difficult to move from chord to chord. You can probably see in the picture that my wrist is really bent.

[image]

Could anybody recommend me on different positions to put my hand in (picture or explanation)?

Comment: Without the picture, this question stops being answerable so I needed to revert back. I cropped it hard, in case that was the issue

Answer (score 4):

I think you’ve figured out your own problem, the extremely bent wrist will cause a lot of tension and discomfort in your left hand because you’re compressing all the tendons, ligaments and muscles in the palm side of your hand.

There are a few things you can try to make yourself straighten that wrist. Keep in mind it has to have some bend, not be completely straight. The main one is to angle the guitar so the headstock and neck are a little higher. That way you’re not reaching down and then having to bend the wrist back up to reach the low notes on the fingerboard. You can also try moving your elbow back a bit. If your elbow is too far forward in relation to the neck your wrist will naturally bend more.

Another couple of things you can try for more comfort is first, if your thumb is in the middle of your 4 fingers try moving it a little more towards your first finger. This should release a little tension in your palm. Also, try not to squeeze with the thumb. The last thing I would suggest is leave your middle finger straight, not tucked down towards the lower strings. Since it’s not playing a note it’s better to have it in a more relaxed position. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try playing with the guitar on your other leg, like a classical guitar.  Or play with your strap on as if you were standing.  Make the guitar high enough that you don't have to reach for the chord.  You are unnecessarily contorting your hand (and back) by sitting like that.  This is a common problem, I had it too what I was young.  In my opinion your fingering of the power chord is fine.  I prefer to use the ring and pinky too, just like a regular bar chord.  Some players bar the 5th and octave with the ring finger.

Answer (score 2):

In that picture, I would say you aren't playing a powerchord. You look like you are just playing an F. I would play the F powerchord in that position just with my index finger and my pinky, with my wrist being nearly straight.

[image]

If you do wish to play the full chord, I would angle the guitar up so the wrist still isn't having to bend so much.